Book about a guy playing a simulation game
Trying to track down a book I read in middle school (23 now), about a guy/boy playing a simulation game. I don’t know much else, except that he played that simulation game. In the game he was like a governor, leader or God (not sure which one describes it the best) where he controlled the people and made decisions for the world/city.

This is incredibly tropey. I can think of a dozen books and stories that match. Can you offer any more details?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Depending where you are middle school might be ages 9-12 or 11-14; can you give us an approximate year?  And is there a science fiction element to this book?  Does the protagonist enter his virtual world, or directly interact with its inhabitants?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers give you an excellent opportunity to [edit] more details into your question, e.g. "I know it's not The Peristalsis Factor because he was definitely using a command-line system, not cutting edge VR tech, and the civilization he was governing was distinctively Mesoamerican."

https://www.amazon.com/CivCEO-Lit-Accidental-Champion-Book-ebook/dp/B07YRTVLMZ would be too recent.

Based on the scant details, might it be The Gadget Factor by Sandy Landsman as per YA (pre-1990) novel: Student writes simulation in which time travel drains prehistoric natural resources, needs to stop from occurring for real?

Two college freshmen create the ultimate computer game, a universe built to their own specifications, but complications arise when their formulas for time travel also work in the real world.


A single HC release in 1984 seems a long shot to be still around 30-ish years later.  Not to mention the time travel aspect is distinct enough to be memorable, versus just world management.

The question is pretty sparse in details, but what little there is would almost match "The Short Ones" by Raymond E. Banks.
"Almost match" because "The Short Ones" is an anthologized story, not a full-length book. It's an involved story about a political candidate performing the governing simulation that is required to qualify for public office.
Might be novella length.
It's answered here.
If that is not it, then I agree with the comment that the theme is very tropey, and it could be a long search.
